# MySQL Point precision for large numbers (eg IPv6)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to do IPv6 address range matching using LineString and Point. But I believe this question is more related to how MySQL handles large number precision in general. (Note the following works without issues with smaller numbers, i.e. IPv4 decimal representation).

For IPv4, the ranges are defined as `LineString(Point(-1, ip_start), Point(1, ip_end))`.

I seem to be losing precision when creating a `Point()` with a large number, therefore my range matching is flawed.

```
MariaDB [mydb]> set @point=Point(0, 42541828702485584113142439188939931648);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mydb]> select astext(@point);
+-------------------------------+
| astext(@point)                |
+-------------------------------+
| POINT(0 4.254182870248558e37) |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mydb]> select st_y(@point);
+----------------------+
| st_y(@point)         |
+----------------------+
| 4.254182870248558e37 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mydb]> select cast(st_y(@point) as Decimal(39));
+----------------------------------------+
| cast(st_y(@point) as Decimal(39))      |
+----------------------------------------+
| 42541828702485580000000000000000000000 |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mydb]>
```

How can I use a `Point()` with large numbers accurately?

Comment: Note: I store the IPv6 addresses as a binary(16), and looking for a range using `BETWEEN range_start AND range_end` works in most cases. Except I have overlapping ranges and it creates long execution times in some cases.

Comment: Sorry, you will have to abandon the use of `SPATIAL` tools for IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

`SPATIAL` functions (`st_x`, `point`, etc) work with `DOUBLEs`, not `DECIMAL`.

`DECIMAL(39)` should work.  But why not just keep it as a string or hex string (`VARCHAR(39) CHARACTER SET ascii`) or `BINARY(16)`?

Please explain your ultimate goal that led you to want to use Spatial tools.

Here is code to handle ranges of IP addresses (separate code for IPv4 or IPv6):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges

Comment: As I commented above, I have overlapping ranges. I need to be able to say, IP address X belongs to subnet Y to Z, which is itself contained in a larger subnet. This way, I can find the addressing hierarchy. It all works fine with IPv4 addresses.

Comment: @jrm - I added a link to how to store and efficiently retrieve when subnets are involved.  (And, yes, it deals with comparisons and minimal arithmetic for 128-bit numbers.)

Comment: Thanks Rick, I actually saw your website before. Unfortunately as you state, this works great for non overlapping ranges. Which is the reason why I had to use Spatial tools instead.

Comment: @jrm - Perhaps overlapping ranges can be broken up into sufficiently small pieces?  The splitting could be automatic (with the addition of a bunch more code in the stored procs).